# My jquery menu doesn't want to work properly

Tags: jquery, menu, tabs

I'm making a tab menu for school. But i'm struggling with my Jquery. 
My idea for the menu was to open a tab and let the textblock roll out that works fine but when i want to open a other tab it goes back up right after i press it. because tab1 is the only one that works, i just don't know how to fix it. I would really appreciate if someone could help. The problem is in this block of J-query.

my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/embedded/result/

```
$('#tab4, #tab3, #tab2,').click(function() {
    $('#tab4, #tab3, #tab2, #tab1').animate({
        height: '100px',
     }, 0, function() {
        // Animation complete.

    });
    $('#textblok1,#textblok2,#textblok3,#textblok4').animate({
        height: '0px',
    }, 0, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? When the user clicks a tab, should the clicked tab open and the other tabs close? What about the Textblocks?

Comment: Also, are the textblocks html within the tabs html?

Comment: @videsignz if start the page, the textblock is down and the first tab is connected, if i want to open the other tab i have to click it it works fine untill there. because textblock 1 goes up and tab 1 goes up and then tab 2 and textblock 2 come down but won't stay down they go up immediately.

Comment: I wanted to post my full jquery. But stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to do that. So i had to cut out the other part.

Comment: Take a look at this... http://jsfiddle.net/WbQwC/4/

Comment: Revised with some css http://jsfiddle.net/WbQwC/6/

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere on this?

Comment: Not really i just figured jsfiddle out here is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/embedded/result/ its not really the same as in the browser it laggs a bit but it works

Comment: i hope that clears up my very bad explanation

Comment: Multiple click events for same elements? Not at all desirable.

Comment: it should work with one click it acts weird because it does not work well yet.

Comment: Here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/7/

Comment: There is way to much script, it should be cut down more like you see in the last fiddle I linked if possible

Comment: Cleaned up css http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/18/

Comment: @Scott Kemp You should use the code in this fiddle to stop existing animations if another tab is clicked http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/20/

Comment: thank you very much i just started webdesigning on my school so im not good at it yet. but one last question. it works perfectly on jsfiddle but in my browser it does nothing. do i need to change thinks in my html like (this) that you put there? because i changed some things and it still didn't work in my browser

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/21/ i tried this but it doesn't work in jsfiddle now either yours does but doesnt work in my browser. Maybe i made a dumb mistake. I'm not good at html right now.

Comment: Do you have JQuery linked to the page?

Comment: You shouldnt have to mess with this... http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/23/

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is at the end of the script, thus after all is said and done, the text blocks close.

```
$('#textblok1,#textblok2,#textblok3,#textblok4').animate({
    height: '0px',
}, 0, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

The reason it is not happening when you click tab1 is because the above animation is not bound to tab1

```
$('#tab4, #tab3, #tab2, *MISSING TAB1* ').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

DEMO here: http://jsfiddle.net/6dwvs/19/

I bound the clicks to the classes rather than IDs. See if it makes any sense to you.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs').each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function(event){
            $('.tabs').css('height','100px');
            $('.blocks').css('height','0px');
            $(this).animate({height: '110px'}, 200);
            $('.blocks').eq(index).animate({height: '500px'}, 2500);
        });
    });
});​
```

EDIT: modified the JS slightly + explanation as follows:

There are equal number of tabs and blocks. So I tied the first tabs to the first block by `.eq(index)`. For a particular index of tabs, the same index is animated.

If index = 0, `.eq(index)` targets the **first** element from the list of elements selected, for index = 1, **second** element and so on...

Comment: @ Pulkit can you explain .eq(index) to me?